# Replace dash character between three or more number separate by dash with space in sentence

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace dash between **three or more number** (each number has only one digit, i.e number from 0 - 9) separate by dash with one space in an sentence. What is the good solution to done this task ?

Sample Input:

```
4-2-2-1 kim yoong-yun
4 -2 - 2 - 1 and 4 - 5
1-2-3-4-5
1-5
4 - 5
```

Expected Output:

```
4 2 2 1 kim yoong-yun
4 2 2 1 and 4 - 5
1 2 3 4 5
1-5         // will not replace
4 - 5       // will not replace
```

I know i can done this by this complex method:

```
String sentence = "4-2-3-1";
Pattern pCode = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:\\d ?- ?){2,}\\d");
Matcher mCode = pCode.matcher(sent);
while (mCode.find()) {
    sentence = mCode.replaceFirst(mCode.group(0).replaceAll(" ?- ?", " "));
    mCode = pCode.matcher(sent);
}
System.out.print(sentence) // 4 2 3 1
```

But can I done in one replace, or any simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 9+, you may use [`Matcher#replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) method:

```
String sentence = "4-2-3-1";
Pattern pCode = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d(?:\\s?-\\s?\\d){2,}\\b");
Matcher mCode = pCode.matcher(sentence);
String result = mCode.replaceAll(x -> x.group().replace("-", " ") );
System.out.println( result ); // => 4 2 3 1
```

See the [online Java demo](https://ideone.com/0yWFdD). In earlier versions, use

```
String sentence = "4-2-3-1";
Pattern pCode = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d(?:\\s?-\\s?\\d){2,}\\b");
Matcher mCode = pCode.matcher(sentence);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (mCode.find()) {
    mCode.appendReplacement(sb,  mCode.group().replace("-", " "));
}
mCode.appendTail(sb);
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/yHrEEo).

The regex is a bit modified to follow the best practices (quantified parts should be moved as far to the right as possible):

```
\b\d(?:\s?-\s?\d){2,}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ynaxBk/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d`  - a single digit
- `(?:\s?-\s?\d){2,}` - two or more occurrences of:

  - `\s?-\s?` - a `-` enclosed with one or zero whitespace
  - `\d` - a single digit
- `\b` - word boundary

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function

```
private static String unDash(String input) {
    String[] splitString = input.split("\\s*-\\s*");
    if(splitString.length < 3){
        return input;
    } else {
        return String.join(" ", splitString);
    }
}
```

Split is done using `"\\s*-\\s*"` which takes care of trimming the String after splitting it by '-'. `String.join` can be used to combine the spilt String using a delimiter, which in our case is `" "`.

Comment: This will lead me to error on text is a string sequence, ex: `replace-dash-character-between-three`. But i will consider using this solution to my project if it not affect to other cases!

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a 1-liner:

```
String s2 = s1.matches("(\\d+[ -]+){2,}\\d") ? s1.replaceAll("[ -]+", " ") : s1;
```

Your logic is “replace separators if there’s more than 3 numbers”, and this code captures that succinctly.

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/TXFS1Y).

Comment: Sr, it also replace if number sequence not separate by  dash, ex: `4D2-3-1`

Comment: @NguyễnVănHiếu see amended answer (although your examples did not suggest such input would be possible)

Comment: @NguyễnVănHiếu you shouldn't update the question like that, because now it's a *different* question. All answers, which may help others, are now invalid. Please undo the edit and ask a *new* question.